# populate dropdown list based on the previous list (mvc3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 dropdownlists and I want on selecting the first one, trigger the second ddl and show specific data from the db. for example first ddl1 contains (states) and ddl2 will dynamically display its cities.

controller loads the states:

```
  ViewBag.ddlStates= new SelectList(db.State, "StateCode", "Title"); 
  return View();
```

View:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlStates")
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlCities", String.Empty)
```

how would I trigger so when ddl state value is changed, call database and get its cities dynamically.. using AJAX, just to reload the ddl/partialView?

Is it possible on ddlState select call action (PartialViewResult) in the controller to generate dynamically the city list and send it back to the view?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change() event of the first dropdown with jQuery:

```
$('#ddlStates').on('change', function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Controller/GetCities',
        data: $(this).val(),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#ddlCities').html(response);
        }
    });

});
```

'Controller/GetCities' will be the route to an action that returns a partial view with you new list of City `<option>`s based on the selected val that was posted.

The action you posted to would look something like this:

```
           [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCities(GetCitiesViewModel model)
    {
        var selectedState = model.ddlStates;
        IEnumerable<CityViewModel> cities = GetCitiesInState(selectedState);
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> filteredItems =
            cities.Select(c => new SelectListItem {Text = c.Name, Value = c.CityId.ToString()});

        return PartialView("CityList", filteredItems);
    }

    private IEnumerable<CityViewModel> GetCitiesInState(int stateId)
    {
        // Just returning a list regardless of state ID. But you would look the cities up by state here.
        return new List<CityViewModel>
            {
                new CityViewModel {CityId = 1, Name = "London"},
                new CityViewModel {CityId = 2, Name = "Birmingham"},
            };
    }

    public class CityViewModel
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetCitiesViewModel
    {
        public int ddlStates { get; set; }
    }
```

With a view something like this:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>
@{ Layout = null; }

@foreach (var city in Model)
{
    <option value="@city.Value">@city.Text</option>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar on one of my sites.  I use a controller action that returns the cities as Json.  The jQuery I'm using clears and disables the city dropdown when there isn't a value selected for state.

Here is my markup

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateCode)
@Html.DropDownList("StateCode", string.Empty)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityID)
@Html.DropDownList("CityID", string.Empty)
```

Here is the JQuery

```
$("select#StateCode").bind('change', function () {
    var StateCode = $("select#StateCode option:selected").val();
    if (StateCode == "" || StateCode == 0) 
    {
        $("select#CityID").empty();
        $("select#CityID").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else 
    {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCityiesForState")', { StateCode: StateCode }, function (data) {
            $("select#CityID").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, c) {
                $('select#CityID').append('<option value="' + c.Value + '">' + c.Text + '</option>');
            });
            $("select#CityID").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("select#CityID option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
        });
    }
});
```

Controller Action

```
public JsonResult GetCityiesForState(string stateCode) {
    var cities = repository.getCities(stateCode);
    return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```